# Can a github collaborator create package in Github package registry?

Tags: github, github-package-registry, github-packages

I have a private github repository and in that repository there are some collaborators. They can't create new packages but they can publish to existing packages created by me as I'm the creator of the repository.

Is there any way that my collaborators will be able to create new packages and publish.

Comment: Note: they can write package code as they have that access as collaborator. But getting error on publish that they don’t have permission for create_package.

Comment: We can read this as well: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/36020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same "create_package" permission issue. I think external collaborators were able to publish new packages in the past. But this no longer works.

Here's the response from GitHub's support team: "In order to publish an org scoped package, the actor performing the publish should be a member of the organization."

So the short answer to your question seems to be "no", at least for scoped packages (which it was for my case)

Comment: Great!
I've checked and found the answer effective. It gives the answer and to solve the problem.
Thank you [@restfulhead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2965919/restfulhead)

Answer (score 2):

I have created a demo organization in my personal github account and transferred the ownership of one of my pet-project repositories to that organization.

After that I have added one of my colleagues as a member in my newly created demo organization and tried publishing an npm-package.

**Voilà it worked**, we were able to successfully publish an npm-package after being a member of the organiztion.